# Typical time needed to transfer books to Kindle 10th Paperwhite via email

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, amazon

**tl;dr** *I've sent a number of files to my Kindle 10th's private email address about 3,5 hour ago and there is no reaction so far -- neither return / rejection email nor books appearing in the device.*

*Is this normal or how can I speed up this process?*

---

When I have registered my "private" emails address for my Kindle 3rd generation ten years ago, I needed about 10-15 minutes between sending an attachment to that address and actually seeing a book in my device.

If there was any kind of error (format not supported, file too big for the conversion engine etc.) then the response / rejection email also needed no more than 15 minutes to arrive.

Has this changed over 10 years or with the Kindle 10th Paperwhite edition?

It is now 3.5 hours since I've sent a number of books to my freshly registered Kindle's email address and... there's nothing. No rejection emails and no books actually appearing in my Librardy / Downloaded section.

Since I wanted to quickly transfer a kind of lot of books then by accident I tested probably all possible situations:

- Sending one ebook per emails vs. sending many files attached to a single email
- Sending small files (less than 1 MB) vs reading Gmail's maximum (25 MB)
- Sending different file formats, including: PDF, DOCX, AZW and MOBI etc.

All for nothing. Three and a half hours has passed and I neither have access to my books on my brand new Paperwhite nor I have any notification / response in my inbox that something went wrong.

Is this normal situation? Is there any way that can I speed up this process?

Comment: From what device are you attempting to send the files to you Paperwhite ?

Comment: @Stefanovitch From my local PC (Windows 10), as I did for past 10 years. I only had a 2-3 years break. Because it took me that time since I stopped using my old Kindle 3 till I started using my new Kindle 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Amazon service only it seems that during this course of 10 years Amazon has change its on-line converter policy.

Right now, if someone from an unauthorised email address will try to send a content to your Kindle / your Kindle's emails address then that person will not be notified at all. Only you (Kindle owner) will get a notification to your own inbox.

I am more than sure that this was different 10 years ago (with Kindle 3rd) and that then the person trying to send anything to your Kindle was notified that conversion or transfer failed due to fact that sender is not among authorised email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I have had anything that resembles a commercial book be silently rejected, while clearly non-commercial documents (personal documents, scraped web serial novels) go through successfully (in about 20min), even if they're very long. That may be the issue here. I stopped using it for that reason.

Try sending an obviously non-commercial document and see if that one goes through.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Send to Kindle ?  It's a free application from Amazon. Install it on your PC and select which file[s],you want to transfer to which device. You can drag a bunch of files onto its icon on the desktop. My experience is that they all get transferred from my PC to Kindle Fire HD in nanoseconds.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. My question was not on _how to send files to Kindle as fast as possible_, but rather _why the method used for many years in the past is now working so slow or doesn't work at all_. See my answer for more details. Let me also say that I can download any purchased book from my on-line bookstore in Kindle format (I am _not_ purchasing books directly at Amazon) and send it to my Kindle over an email (as in question) even on my mobile phone, to which I can't connect my Kindle and where I cannot install any kind of PC software. But, thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: @trejder  Forgive if I missed your point !  I was responding to your question, "Is there any way that can I speed up this process?".